# Error reading file using Scanner

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read a file with the scanner and get some variables. Here is what the file looks like (disregard the extra line in between):

ControlType: 1

FIRE @ 541.0, 387.0

FIRE @ 252.0, 198.0

PANT @ 522.0, 174.0

PANT @ 268.0, 399.0

HERO @ 397.0, 287.0

What I need to do is get the control type and store it, get the object type (fire, etc.) and then get the coordinates as floats. What I've gotten so far I think is a start but I'm not sure I understand the error that pops up. I think it may have something to do with the commas in between the floats? This is my code: (the scanner is reading from the string "level" which contains all of the contents of the file. There is no need for new File etc.)

```
// Create a scanner
    Scanner in = new Scanner(level);
    // Move past initial text
    in.next();
    // Get control type
    int controlType = in.nextInt();

    // While there is something to read
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String a = in.next();
        System.out.println(a);

        if (a.equals("FIRE")) {
            in.next();
            float x = in.nextFloat();
            float y = in.nextFloat();
            fires.add(new Fire(x, y, randGen));
        } else if (a.equals("HERO")) {
            in.next();
            float x = in.nextFloat();
            float y = in.nextFloat();
            hero = new Hero(x, y, controlType);
        } else if (a.equals("PANT")) {
            in.next();
            float x = in.nextFloat();
            float y = in.nextFloat();
            pants.add(new Pant(x, y, randGen));
        }
    }
```

And this is the output:

```
FIRE
```

And then these errors:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Unknown Source)
    at Game.loadLevel(Game.java:184)
    at Game.<init>(Game.java:53)
    at Application.setup(Application.java:90)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2373)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1523)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:316)
```

Comment: `@` is not a valid float .

Comment: Fixed that by adding in in.next(), still getting an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error beacause you have an `@` in your input. Your `nextFloat()` method gets that and tried to parse it as a float, but fails. Hence you see the exception.

One way to overcome is, that you add another `in.next()` in you code, to consume the `@`.

eg:

```
while(in.hasNextLine()){
    String a = in.next();
    System.out.println(a);
    in.next();  //consume the @
    //rest of code
```

---

**Edit**

You say that you still get the exception. This is because your numbers are separated by a `,`. You need to consume that too.

You can do this by:

```
if(a.equals("FIRE")){
    in.next();// for @
    String num[] = in.nextLine().split(",");
    float x = Float.parseFloat(num[0].trim());
    float y = Float.parseFloat(num[1].trim());
    fires.add(new Fire(x, y, randGen));
}
```

Comment: Hmm how do I consume that while also getting the float?

Comment: You'll need to strip the , character from any values read in by the scanner. Read it as a string and then parse them manually.

Comment: I've tried printing x right after it is stored but it seems that it's not able to gotten. I still get an error. It seems that calling in.nextFloat() causes errors even if I call it after the @

Comment: Using an array worked but I'm still curious as to why the other method wasn't working.

Comment: @dj1121 The "other method" wasn't working because the scanner gets the input including the comma, but is not able to parse it due to the presence of the comma, as Tom pointed out. So, I removed that. Thanks Tom, for pointing it out.

Comment: Your answer? Because I was sure you'll improve it. If there wouldn't be a reaction after a certain amount of time (and you were online on the meantime), then I would have considered it.